# How to beautify xml received as string?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have web service which returns xml as plain string. I need to format it like xml [beautifier does](http://xmlbeautifier.com/). I expect it to be performed on client side by JavaScript. How can I do that? What libraries is better fitted for this task?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to use "JavaScript code prettifier" from Google.

You can find it here: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html.

Follow the setup guide in the link and include the javascript file and then use it like so:

```
prettyPrintOne(XML_TO_BEAUTIFIED, 'xml')
```

Comment: Link is broke..